# Error while trying to copy the file from one folder to a temp folder in JAVA [Access Denied]?

Tags: java, file, io, file-copying

I am  trying to copy a bunch of files from one folder to a temp folder using java but its giving me File not found error(Access Denied)

> The code snippet is:

`         // defining path

```
     Path userDir = Paths.get("somePathString");
     Path tempDir = Files.createTempDirectory(userDir, tempFolder);

    // creating file

    File userDirFile = new File(userDir.toString());
    File tempDirFile = new File((tempDir).toString());


    FileCopyUtils.copy(userDirFile, tempDirFile);

    tempDirFile.deleteOnExit();`
```

> Output

```
`    java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\gitProjects\server\bin\newfolder (Access is denied)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.util.FileCopyUtils.copy(FileCopyUtils.java:63)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)

`
```

Comment: So does the folder actually exist on your machine or not?

Comment: yes it does exist, the only solution seems to be for this problem that creating a seperate file for each file to copy and then copy the file to the newly created file.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem with Netbeans. With a Netbeans package you don't want to place your files directly in the src folder. Instead you want them just inside the package folder.

Also it looks like your (Access is denied). Every file is given a permission which means that only certain users can access that file. Here is the Windows direction to changing file permissions.

You need to set permission for the user controls .

Goto C:\Program Files\
Right click java folder, click properties. Select the security tab.
There, click on "Edit" button, which will pop up PERMISSIONS FOR JAVA window.
Click on Add, which will pop up a new window. In that, in the "Enter object name" box, Enter your user account name, and click okay(if already exist, skip this step).
Now in "PERMISSIONS OF JAVA" window, you will see several clickable options like CREATOR OWNER, SYSTEM, among them is your username. Click on it, and check mark the FULL CONTROL option in Permissions for sub window.
Finally, Hit apply and okay.